# Transforming Lambert Conformal Conic to EPSG:3857

Tags: gdal

I have a map file in a tiff format that is not geo-referenced, but I know the following projection information: +proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84. I would like to transform it into EPSG:3857.

In my first attempt I tried to fix four arbitrary points and perform warping

```
     gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -of GTiff -gcp 19725 11865 1 56 -gcp 103755 12990 23 56 -gcp 112755 80400 23 46 -gcp 8925 78990 1 46 original.tif translated.tif
```

But the coordinates of the corners of the warped image where not as expected and the map was distorted.

```
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  ( 1208480.629, 6678543.890) ( 10d51'21.48"E, 51d19'21.08"N)
    Lower Left  ( 1208480.629, 6678541.123) ( 10d51'21.48"E, 51d19'21.03"N)
    Upper Right ( 1208486.180, 6678543.890) ( 10d51'21.66"E, 51d19'21.08"N)
    Lower Right ( 1208486.180, 6678541.123) ( 10d51'21.66"E, 51d19'21.03"N)
    Center      ( 1208483.404, 6678542.507) ( 10d51'21.57"E, 51d19'21.06"N)
```

After reading many posts, here and elsewhere, I came to this:

1. Converting the UL and LR corners to x and y

   ```
   cs2cs +proj=latlong +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84 +to +init=epsg:3857

   -3.63 57.28 >   -404089.75 7817564.89
   23.76 44.39 >   2644951.10 5525995.28
   ```
2. Geo-referencing the tiff

   ```
   gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -a_ullr -404089.75 7817564.89 2644951.10 5525995.28 original.tif translated.tif
   ```

   The result of gdalinfo translated.tif is as follows:

   ```
   Size is 14735, 11333
   Coordinate System is:
   PROJCS["unnamed",
       GEOGCS["WGS 84",
           DATUM["WGS_1984",
               SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                   AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
               AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
           PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
           UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
           AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
       PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42],
       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",57],
       PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",51.322],
       PARAMETER["central_meridian",10.856],
       PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
       PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
       UNIT["metre",1,
           AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
   Origin = (-404089.750000000000000,7817564.889999999664724)
   Pixel Size = (206.925066168985410,-202.203265684284787)
   Metadata:
     AREA_OR_POINT=Area
     TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
     TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=144
     TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=144
   Image Structure Metadata:
     INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
   Corner Coordinates:
   Upper Left  ( -404089.750, 7817564.890) (146d18'53.31"E, 73d27'53.56"N)
   Lower Left  ( -404089.750, 5525995.280) (158d45'33.92"W, 88d 1'24.64"N)
   Upper Right ( 2644951.100, 7817564.890) (172d26'19.88"W, 64d26'59.68"N)
   Lower Right ( 2644951.100, 5525995.280) (138d13'57.20"E, 73d22'12.76"N)
   Center      ( 1120430.675, 6671780.085) (161d52'17.63"W, 79d37'35.75"N)
   ```

   However, the coordinates of the corners above are completely off. When I attempted to warp it, the image could become so huge that I had to stop the process after a couple of minutes.

   ```
   gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r near -co COMPRESS=LZW translated.tif warped.tif
   ```

   The result of gdalinfo warped.tif is as follows:

   ```
   Corner Coordinates:
   Upper Left  (-20037508.339,29704755.766) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d54'44.28"N)
   Lower Left  (-20037508.339, 9464937.842) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 64d26'59.58"N)
   Upper Right (20037503.600,29704755.766) (179d59'59.85"E, 88d54'44.28"N)
   Lower Right (20037503.600, 9464937.842) (179d59'59.85"E, 64d26'59.58"N)
   Center      (      -2.370,19584846.804) (  0d 0' 0.08"W, 84d41'15.52"N)
   ```

What did I miss?

---

Let's simplify the problem: how do I geo-reference the image file without converting the projection into EPSG:3857?

The first step I took was to embed the projection info and the four corner points:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 -4.226944 57.35083 -gcp 14735 0 27.78 57.59555 -gcp 14735 11333 24.30917 44.06611 -gcp 0 11333 -3.537778 43.6 original.tif georeferenced.tif
```

In the second step I warped georeferenced.tif without specifying a target projection:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -r near georeferenced.tif warped.tif
```

When I checked warped.tif info got the following corner coordinates:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -4.5777770,  57.6508975) ( 10d51'21.36"E, 51d19'21.08"N)
Lower Left  (  -4.5777770,  43.6558450) ( 10d51'21.36"E, 51d19'20.62"N)
Upper Right (  26.7396454,  57.6508975) ( 10d51'22.99"E, 51d19'21.08"N)
Lower Right (  26.7396454,  43.6558450) ( 10d51'22.99"E, 51d19'20.62"N)
```

I was hoping to get:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (0.0, 0.0) (-4.226944, 57.35083,0)
Lower Left  (0.0, 11333.0) (-3.537778, 43.6,0)
Upper Right  (14735.0, 0.0) (27.78, 57.59555,0)
Lower Right  (14735.0, 11333.0) (24.30917, 44.06611,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you GCP's are correct? They should be in the form:

```
-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]*
```

You have one GCP which suggest that your input file is at least 112755 x 80400 pixels (w x h) in size. Its possible of course, but its a large file.

I think you should combine your first attempt with your later `gdalwarp` step. Since `gdalwarp` doesn't take gcp's, and `gdal_translate` can't warp, it takes two steps.

You can output your first step to a `VRT` file, so it takes less processing and disk space.

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -gcp 19725 11865 1 56 -gcp 103755 12990 23 56 -gcp 112755 80400 23 46 -gcp 8925 78990 1 46 original.tif georeferenced.vrt
```

And then warp the VRT:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r near -co COMPRESS=LZW georeferenced.vrt warped.tif
```

Comment: The dimensions of the map file are 14735 pixels x 11333 pixels. The gcps that I have selected are not corner points but points that form a “rectangle” of some even latitudes and longitudes. The UL and LR corners of this rectangle are 1E, 56N and 23E, 46N respectively. Therefore, one of the gcps was set as -gcp 19725 11865 1 56.

I followed your suggestion and the output was the same as before, a distorted map with the following corner coordinates:

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence should read: I followed your suggestion and the output was the same as before, a distorted map with the same corners as in my first attempt.

Comment: I still don't understand why you enter pixel coordinates in the order of 100k pixels when your map is only in the order of 10k. Even for your UL corner you enter pixel coordinates which are beyond the LR corner, are you sure that's correct?

Comment: You were correct about the pixels, by mistake I used twips. But changing it to pixels didn't make a difference. Warping gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -gcp 0 0 -4.226944 57.35083 -gcp 14735 0 27.78 57.59555 -gcp 14735 11333 24.30917 44.06611 -gcp 0 11333 -3.537778 43.6 original.tif georeferenced.vrt (this time using the coordinates of the corner points of the image) produced similar results as in my first attempt.

Comment: That looks better. You probably also need to specify the easting/northing of the GCP's in the LCC projection, instead of degrees (EPSG 4326). So something like: `gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lon_0=10.856 +lat_0=51.322 +lat_1=42 +lat_2=57 +datum=WGS84" -gcp 0 0 -902684.104360112 758856.426488966 -gcp 14735 0 1005006.56754184 808903.653989463 -gcp 14735 11333 1067860.49635805 -704969.405955644 -gcp 0 11333 -1151463.51279552 -741799.037637944`

Comment: We are getting somewhere. I geo-referenced per your suggestion and warped it as before. The output image is more as it expected to be. However, it needs a tweak somewhere because the longitude lines are leaning about 4 degrees to the right and the latitude lines are curving up somewhat.
By the way, how did you figure the easting and northing? I tried cs2cs and gdaltransform without luck.